# Function "on_complete" called before "completed" on kivy app with plyer

Tags: android, python, kivy

It's me again! 
Well, that's really strange. 
I'using kivy for make an App for Android. 
I can use the camera, but or the app resets or do something strange.
Here is the problem:

`def chamar_camera(nome,pc,objeto,label_passa,instance): 

    agora = datetime.now()
    nome_arquivo = '%s_%s_%.4i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i.jpg' % (nome,pc,agora.year,agora.month,agora.day,agora.hour,agora.minute,agora.second)

    # Option 1 - These two lines work:
    #def sair():print 'oi'
    #camera.take_picture(nome_arquivo, sair)

    # Option 2 - These two lines work too:
    def sair(label_passa,nome_arquivo):print 'oi'
    camera.take_picture(nome_arquivo,on_complete=sair(label_passa,nome_arquivo))

    # Option 3 - But these don't:
    #def sair(label_passa,nome_arquivo):label_passa.text = nome_arquivo
    #camera.take_picture(nome_arquivo, on_complete=sair(label_passa,nome_arquivo))

    def on_pause(self):return True
    def on_resume(self):pass`

On option 3, I write a text (nome_arquivo) on a label widget (label_passa), but what happens is that the text is wrote before the camera be activated. So the camera appear, I can take a picture and the App restarts. I also tried just a "def sair(): pass", but this doesn't work. The only thing working is an "print", but on my app I need to write something in that label and update an sqlite database. Any idea why the function is being called before the camera action?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`on_pause` and `on_resume` should be defined as methods of your App class, not (as you have here) functions defined locally within the `chamar_camera` function.

Comment: I put cause I had no more ideas, but the problem is still the same, with or without those two lines.

Comment: And I have this two lines on my App class too.

Comment: One improvement: 
<pre>
    def chamar_camera(nome,pc,media,objeto,label_passa,instance): 
    
        agora = datetime.now()
        nome_arquivo = '%s_%s_%.4i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i_%.2i.jpg' % (nome,pc,agora.year,agora.month,agora.day,agora.hour,agora.minute,agora.second)
        def sair(label_passa,instance):
            label_passa.text = ''
        camera.take_picture(nome_arquivo,   on_complete=partial(sair,label_passa))
<code>
Now the app doesn't restart, and the function is called after using camera, but at first time I use the App it restarts after camera and then no more.